# How to sort range on specified worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to apply VBA code to really large sheets. The idea is that the "My Portfolio.xlsx" filename used below will become a variable so I can run the code against any sheet without having to copy-paste the macro into each sheet.

I can convert a text column to a number datatype.

```vb
Sub ConvertTextToNumber()
Workbooks("My Portfolio.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A9999").NumberFormat = "General"
End Sub
```

This works even if I change the filename. So the general format should be correct.

I am trying to sort the first column (with header) from smallest to largest.

```vb
Sub SortSmallestToLargest()
Workbooks("My Portfolio.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:BT9999").Sort Key1:=Range("A:A"), Order1:=xlAscending
End Sub
```

I've adjusted the Sort part multiple times, changing the Range from "A:A" to "A" to "A2", but none of them work.
I've also tried saying Header=Yes or Header=No, but it always errors.

I get

> Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error

My searches for that error usually refer to giving it out-of-bounds ranges or something else, but everything in the code above should be fine.

I'm thinking the issue stems after the 'Sort' part begins, but no matter what I change or remove, I can't get it to sort the "A" column.

Comment: You always have to fully qualify the range. I mean, in your case you try sorting a range of "Sheet1" but using a `key` from the active sheet. It will work as expected, only if the "Sheet1" is the active one... It should be good to declare a `Worksheet` variable, let us say, `ws`, setting it as the sheet you need and using it as `ws.Range("A2:BT9999").Sort Key1:=ws.Range("A:A"), Order1:=xlAscending`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub SortSmallestToLargest()
    Workbooks("My Portfolio.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:BT9999").Sort Key1:=Workbooks("My Portfolio.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A"), Order1:=xlAscending
End Sub
```

Or perhaps more readable:

```
Sub SortSmallestToLargest()
    with Workbooks("My Portfolio.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1")
        .Range("A2:BT9999").Sort Key1:= .Range("A:A"), Order1:=xlAscending
    end with
End Sub
```

Note, you need to have the dot in the .Range() assignment. I just tripped on that.

Comment: Perfect! I had to re-specify the workbook in the Sort apparently. At least I wasn't super far off. Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your goal is to run a Macro on any workbook without having to copy code into that workbook.

The two best ways I've found to do this are:

1. Use the your personal macro workbook, this is a workbook that excel always opens in the background. So you can store code there and it's always available to run. I generally reference the active workbook in my macros.
2. Save the workbook as an add-in.

I prefer this method as it allows me to share macros or easily remove. Also the personal macro workbook can behave unusually sometimes.

Finally by activating the Macro from the quick access toolbar you ensure the currently active workbook is the untended workbook.